# Why I can't assign function to dict member as documentation states? Vimscript

Tags: vim

I'm trying to do this

```
let myDict = { 'lang': 'vimscript' }

func! MyFunction()
  echo "self exists => " . exists("self")
endfun

call MyFunction()

let myDict.myFunction = MyFunction
call myDict.myFunction()
```

From the docs: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/doc/eval.txt#L161

The output

```
self exists => 0                                                                                                                                                                                           
Error detected while processing /Users/gecko/.vim/plugged/vim-ansible-execute-task/foo.vim:
line    9:
E121: Undefined variable: MyFunction
E15: Invalid expression: MyFunction
line   10:
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: myFunc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the example is plain wrong or it silently assumes that `MyFunction` is a funcref. In both cases, the information is erroneous so you should probably open an issue.

You are supposed to assign a `:help funcref`, not the function itself:

```
let myDict = { 'lang': 'vimscript' }

function! MyFunction()
  echo "self exists => " . exists("self")
endfunction

call myFunction()
" self exists => 0

let myDict.myFunction = function("MyFunction")
call myDict.myFunction()
" self exists => 0
```

Note that in this case, the function doesn't get `self`. If you want `self`, you must add the `dict` attribute, but it will make it impossible to call `myFunction()` directly:

```
let myDict = { 'lang': 'vimscript' }

function! MyFunction() dict
  echo "self exists => " . exists("self")
endfunction

call myFunction()
" E725

let myDict.myFunction = function("MyFunction")
call myDict.myFunction()
" self exists => 1
```

This may or may not be a problem for you.

See `:help dictionary-function` and `:help anonymous-function` for a simpler approach if you don't care about calling `myFunction()` directly:

```
let myDict = { 'lang': 'vimscript' }

function! myDict.myFunction()
  echo "self exists => " . exists("self")
endfunction

call myDict.myFunction()
" self exists => 1
```